# Model's property of type List<int> instantiating from POST despite value passed being null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `ajax` to perform a post to an action with this declaration:

```
public ActionResult MonitorReport(FilterCaseViewModel model)
```

Amongst other things the `FilterCaseViewModel` has this property:

```
public class FilterCaseViewModel
{
    public List<int> Status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using `JSON` for the content type, The `JSON` object starts like this (I've omitted the rest of it as it's quite long).

```
{ model: {"TextSearch":null,"Generic1":null,"Generic2":null,"Status":null,"Team":null,"Client":null
```

Looking at the request form I'm getting an empty string interpreted for `Status`

[image]
[image]

Despite this however the `Status` property has been instantiated and a value of `0` has been added to the list.

[image]

I would expect the `Status` property to be `null`, why is this not the case?

**Note:** Status is not set anywhere in the constructor.

Comment: Your sending a name/value pair for `Status` so the `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize your collection (and it will be an empty collection). If you omit the name, it will be `null`. But I cannot duplicate what your claiming - that it contains one item.

Comment: Also what is that first image - it looks like your inspecting the the `AllKeys` of `Request.Form` which will be empty for an ajax request with `contentType='application/json'` (which suggest you making a normal submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't explicitly set the contentType to JSON however the I assumed (probably incorrectly) that because I passed in a JSON object it would automatically set the content type to that.

Comment: In fact the content type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' I'm gonna try seinding JSON instead.

Comment: You cannot send arrays using the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` - it would need to be in the format `[0].Status=1, [1].Status=2` etc. Other wise you need to use `contentType='application/json'` and `JSON.stringify()` to stringify the data

Answer (score -2):

Any integer in .net by default will hold 0 as a value. If you need a `null` as a default value of an integer variable, you need to define it nullable. Like this-

```
int? i;
```

More details can be found here - [Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types)

Comment: My type is not `int` it is of type `List<int>` which is a reference object so it can be null.

Comment: Did you *read* the question? OP is asking why a `List<int>` is getting set a value from an empty string. This has nothing to do with `int` vs. `int?`.